# cURL POST request without body as none

Tags: curl

I am trying to publish a request to API in cURL without body but it still gives me 415 ERROR.
The same exact request works in Postman without problem.
Not sure what is incorrect in cURL command line which is not giving me the output as Postman.

Comment: Curl req and response:

Req:

curl -L -X POST "https://oic-nam-dev1-idkcmbezyl4e-ia.integration.ocp.oraclecloud.com:443/ic/api/integration/v1/flows/rest/TESTRESTPOCSERVICE/1.0/id/xxx.abc@mycompany.com" -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxx" -w 'HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}' -d ""



<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error 415--Unsupported Media Type</TITLE>

Comment: Postman logs:

Request Headers
Authorization: Basic XXX
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.24.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 73262804-b44f-47bc-880f-cb967399a258
Host: oic-nam-dev1-idkcmbezyl4e-ia.integration.ocp.oraclecloud.com:443
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: ORA_FUSION_PREFS=v1.0~XXXX Response Body

SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting postman request to curl.

https://idratherbewriting.com/learnapidoc/docapis_curl_with_petstore.html#export-postman-to-curl